# Preventing the use of junit4 libraries in a project

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, junit4, junit5

There is an existing software project, developed and maintained by several developers.
The IDE is IntelliJ, the build tool is [Maven](https://maven.apache.org). The project has had both JUnit 4 and JUnit 5 tests. We want to refactor and use only JUnit 5 from now.

The problem is that code completion from the IDE still offers both JUnit 4 and JUnit 5, and devs might accidentally use them, e.g. `org.junit.Assert.assertTrue` instead of `org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue`.

Is there an elegant, automated way to detect the use of JUnit 4 classes as early as possible?

Comment: Exclude  the vintage engine of JUnit Jupiter also exclude any dependency and make an enforcer rule to prevent adding a dependency ...than a build will simply fail during compilation ...

Answer (score 7):

There are a few options once all the tests are converted from JUnit 4 to JUnit 5.

The most straightforward option is to exclude JUnit 4 from the classpath.  Depending on what libraries are being used, some dependency-level exclusions might need to be added to avoid transitively pulling in JUnit 4.  This setup will cause the build to fail at the compilation stage if any JUnit 4 imports are in use.  It will also generally prevent the IDE from providing JUnit 4 classes as auto-completion options.

This option may not be available if another testing library requires JUnit 4.  For instance, the [Testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org) library still requires JUnit 4 to be on the classpath, even if the tests themselves are written in JUnit 5 ([testcontainers-java#970](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/970)).  In this case, one option is to write a [Checkstyle](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io) rule to disallow non-Jupiter JUnit imports, and to have the build fail when Checkstyle failures occur.

The relevant Checkstyle config:

```xml
<module name="IllegalImport">
    <property name="regexp" value="true"/>
    <!-- Reject any org.junit import that's not also org.junit.jupiter: -->
    <property name="illegalClasses" value="^org\.junit\.(?!jupiter\.).+"/>
</module>
```

Answer (score 5):

1. If `junit` 4.x is not needed on classpath, you can remove it from classpath and add to the banned dependencies list of `maven-enforcer-plugin`:

   ```
                <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-enforcer-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enforce</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <bannedDependencies>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>junit:junit</exclude>

                                    </excludes>
                                </bannedDependencies>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
   ```
2. if `junit` 4.x is required to be on classpath (e.g. `testcontainers` still depend on it), but you do not want other people to write tests using it -- use [restrict-imports-enforcer-rule](https://github.com/skuzzle/restrict-imports-enforcer-rule):

   ```
                <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-enforcer-plugin.version}</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>de.skuzzle.enforcer</groupId>
                        <artifactId>restrict-imports-enforcer-rule</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enforce</id>
                        <configuration>

                            <rules>
                                <RestrictImports>
                                    <reason>Please instead use Junit 5.</reason>
                                    <bannedImports>
                                        <bannedImport>org.junit.Test</bannedImport>
                                        <bannedImport>org.junit.runner.RunWith</bannedImport>
                                        <bannedImport>org.junit.Before</bannedImport>
                                        <bannedImport>org.junit.After</bannedImport>
                                    </bannedImports>
                                </RestrictImports>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
   ```